# Operaciones con subqueries

Tags: mysql

tengo una tabla con lo siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando con un mismo query extraer dos variables de esta tabla y operar en  el mismo query estas dos variables la cuestión es que me arroja el siguiente error cuando ejecuto el query 
"Error de SQL(1241): Operand should contain 1 column(s)

El query que estoy ejecutando es el siguiente:

```
SELECT
 UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Time) as time_sec,
    (SELECT Time,VarValue 
  FROM calderasjct.calderas_gas_variables
      WHERE VarName = "CAL_TEMPGASES" 
      ORDER BY Time ASC
  ) as TGC,
  ( SELECT Time,(sqrt(sqrt(VarValue / 14.5037))*100)  
    FROM calderasjct.calderas_gas_variables
      WHERE VarName = "CAL_TEMPGASES" 
      ORDER BY Time ASC
  ) as TVS,

TGC - TVS as value,
'DIFERENCIA'  as metric

FROM calderasjct.calderas_gas_variables
WHERE  $__timeFilter(Time)
ORDER BY Time ASC
```

Comment: En cada subconsulta obtienes DOS columnas y les pones un solo alias

Comment: Oh  si, no se como se me pasó por alto, ya quite "Time" pero ya me sale Uknown column TGC in the field list, creería que es porque está dentro de  el query principal y como tal esas columnas no existen en la tabla original, alguna forma de arreglarlo ? si hacer esas tablas en la original

Comment: Ahí el lío está en que los alias se pueden usar sólo en HAVING, ORDER BY y GROUP BY. En otra parte de la consulta no van a funcionar [(documentación)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html). Ahí deberías usar una CTE o una subconsulta

Comment: Hay algo que no entiendo de tu consulta, resolviendo los problemas que ya tiene, estarías restando la variable `VarValue`  de cada fila, con otro valor pero que se basa en el mismo `VarValue` de la misma fila. ¿podrías explicar que es lo que intentas hacer?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Mira en efecto todas comparten un mismo nombre de columna de variable y nombre de columna de valor , lo que no comporten es el nombre como tal de la variable es decir "CAL_TEMPGASES", "CLAFLUJOV", etc.
Justo a partir de  ese inconveniente es que planté esa manera de hacerlo mediante subqueries, extrayendo datos(Var Value )de la misma tabla y asignándole un nombre diferente de manera virtualizada sí podría decirse así.

de momento el query iria asi:

Comment: SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(Time) as time_sec,
   (SELECT VarValue 
     FROM calderasjct.calderas_gas_variables
    WHERE VarName = "CAL_TEMPGASES" 
    ORDER BY Time ASC
   ) as TGC,
   ( SELECT (sqrt(sqrt(VarValue / 14.5037))*100)  
     FROM calderasjct.calderas_gas_variables
    WHERE VarName = "CAL_TEMPGASES" 
    ORDER BY Time ASC
   ) as TVS,

 TGC - TVS AS value

FROM calderasjct.calderas_gas_variables
WHERE  $__timeFilter(Time)
ORDER BY Time ASC

pero sigo obteniendo Uknown column TGC in the field list